# I want to `setAppId` for specific file without using Google File Picker

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I want to `setAppId` for specific file in google drive to get permission to access this file with my application. But I only know that we can `setAppId()` when using Google File Picker. Did anyone have another approach to request user `setAppId()` for specific file? Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you already have with the Google File Picker? What files are missing?
I would take a look at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs#gdata) where there is more information of the variable meaning.
Also in the Drive API there is not a filed in File metadata being AppID. But take a look at [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-sdk) to see the steps to make this UI integration with Drive.

Comment: Dear @Raserhin, in documentation that you sent me said that `The AppId and the client ID, used for authorizing access to a user's files, must be contained in the same app`. But in google file picker I don't set app id so know I can't open user's files. I don't know how google verify that file can open by app based on AppId and ClientID and do you have any approach that can set it manually. Thank you.